# Как мне сделать элемент в элементе ООП

Tags: c#, ооп

Т.е я хочу чтобы у меня было так

```
BingElement a;
Console.WriteLine(a.IMAGE);
```

Но как я понял, я делаю не так все, и у меня не работает

```
public class BingElement
        {
            public class ImageEl 
            {
                const string IMAGE = "image";
            }
            public class SearchEl 
            {
                const string SEARCH = "search";
            }
        }
```

Как мне поправить это?
Или если я не правильно вообще делаю, как мне стоит сделать?

Я пытаюсь сделать гибкую систему аргументов(объектов) для методов

Comment: Я вообще ничего не понял

Comment: элемент в элементе  - это что - наследник что ли?

Comment: Достаточно свойства `public string Image { get; set; }`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский мне нужно сделать гибкую систему. Просто сделать const stringи очень просто, и не правильно как я думаю

Comment: Как вариант, может быть свойство `public ImageEl Image { get; set; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так это делается

```cs
public class ImageEl 
{
    public string Name;
}

public class SearchEl 
{
    public string Text;
}

public class BingElement
{
    public ImageEl Image;
    public SearchEl Search;
}
```

Обращаться как-то так.

```cs
BingElement element = new BingElement();
element.Image = new ImageEl();
element.Image.Name = "Image";
element.Search = new SearchEl();
element.Search.Text = "Text";
```

Еще есть такая штука в C# как [свойства](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php), для публичных членов класса лучше использовать свойства.

Константы - это статические члены класса, они не сильно относятся к ООП, а скорее просто помогают писать красивый код.

То есть если у вас такая константа

```cs
public class ImageEl 
{
    public const string IMAGE = "image";
}
```

то обращаться к ней надо так

```cs
Console.WriteLine(ImageEl.IMAGE);
```